# Serverless - How to access Aws secret manager as environment variable

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

Currently, I am accessing AWS parameter store value as environment variable. It is defined in serverless yml like so:

```
environment:
    XYZ_CREDS: ${ssm:xyzCreds}
```

In code, I access this like so `process.env.XYZ_CREDS`
I need to move this value to AWS secret manager and access the xyzCreds in the same way.
Based on the [serverless document](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/#reference-variables-using-aws-secrets-manager) I tried like so -

```
  custom:
    xyzsecret: ${ssm:/aws/reference/secretsmanager/XYZ_CREDS_SECRET_MANAGERa~true} 
  environment:
    XYZ_CREDS: ${self:custom.xyzsecret}}
```

But it's not working. Please help!

Comment: What exactly is the name of your parameter in SSM?

Comment: @ThalesMinussi - xyzCreds in parameter store, which was working. Now I created a param in secret manager - XYZ_CREDS_SECRET_MANAGERa

Comment: Basically, I need to populate AWS secret manager data into environment variable.

Comment: This is new to me. I have extensively used Parameter Store only, never Secrets Manager. I just checked the docs and your code looks good. Does the deploy user have access to Secrets Manager? Can't really think of anything else apart from that (well, maybe a typo on the secret name, but I am sure you have triple checked it already). I am sorry.

Comment: @zacurry have you solved this issue? I'm not able to access the property inside json object of the secret xyzsecret....

Answer (score 7):

After struggling with this issue by myself, I found the solution that worked for me.

Assume that we have a secret XYZ_CREDS where we store user and password key-value pairs. AWS Secrets manager stores them in JSON format: `{"user": "test", "password": "xxxx"}`

Here is how to put user and password into Lambda function environment variables:

```
custom:
  xyzsecret: ${ssm:/aws/reference/secretsmanager/XYZ_CREDS~true}
myService:
  handler: index.handler
  environment:
    username: ${self:custom.xyzsecret.user}
    password: ${self:custom.xyzsecret.password}
```

I'm using Serverless 1.73.1 for deploying to CloudFormation.

Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the name of your secret in secrets manager is correct. I think you might have an "a" after manager before the decryption.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a serverless plugin since I faced the same issue. You check out the plugin here: https://github.com/robin-thomas/serverless-aws-secrets

You can have your environment variables that look like this:

```
MYSQL_USERNAME=secret:MYSQL_USERNAME
MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret:MYSQL_PASSWORD
```

The plugin will then load the secret from AWS Secrets Manager, and then replace values of `MYSQL_USERNAME` and `MYSQL_PASSWORD`.

So when you access `process.env.MYSQL_USERNAME` within your lambda, the secret is already available.

Answer (score 0):

Secret manager stores in key value/json format.So specify the variables individually

Eg.

```
   environment:
     user_name: ${self:custom.xyzsecret}.username
     password: ${self:custom.xyzsecret}.password
```

otherwise pass secret manager name and decrypt using aws-sdk in the code

```
 environment:
     secretkey_name:XYZ_CREDS_SECRET_MANAGERa
```

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't work for me. If I reference the key as ${self.custom.xyzsecret}.password then environment variable contains: {"username": "xxx", "password": "yyyyy"}.password instead of resolving it into password value.

Comment: can you share how looks custom variable secret manager reference